# Could NOT find LIBBFD (missing: LIBBFD_BFD_LIBRARY LIBBFD_IBERTY_LIBRARY LIBBFD_OPCODES_LIBRARY LIBBFD_INCLUDE_DIRS)

Tags: linux, shell

While configuring cmake in linux getting dependency error

```
-- checking for module 'zlib'
--   package 'zlib' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):

-- checking for module 'libcurl'
--   package 'libcurl' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find LibElf (missing: LIBELF_LIBRARIES LIBELF_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

And not able to find the rpm packages for redhat using "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)" machine, Please suggest me the path or location from where i can get these dependency rpm packages for redhat linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could NOT find LIBBFD
>
> package 'zlib' not found , package 'libcurl' not found

"package" means a package config file e.g. /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/zlib.pc

Please use yum to decide a package name, like :

```
yum provides */libbfd.so
yum provides */zlib.pc
yum provides */libz.so
yum provides */libcurl.pc
yum provides */libcurl.so
```

Installing the packages :

```
# yum install binutils-devel zlib-devel libcurl-devel
```

---

Ref. comment about kcov :

"kcov" : `# yum install elfutils-devel`

```
cd build/ && cmake .. && make
.
.
[ 98%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/kcov-system-daemon.dir/version.c.o
Linking CXX executable kcov-system-daemon
[100%] Built target kcov-system-daemon
```

Comment: Hi Larsen sorry for late reply, I Already configured  all dependencies

[root@abc build]# yum install binutils-devel zlib-devel libcurl-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.den1.denvercolo.net
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: sjc.edge.kernel.org
Package binutils-devel-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libcurl-devel-7.29.0-46.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: »» While configuring cmake «« : When 64bits packages are rejected, then it could be suspected that the application is 32bits / i686 only → `# yum install binutils-devel.i686 zlib-devel.i686 libcurl-devel.i686` . ... ... Which software are you trying to configure with cmake ? ?

Comment: »» Trying to configure kcov on Centos


»»  -- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found LIBBFD: /usr/lib64/libbfd.so
-- Found LibElf: /usr/lib64/libelf.so
-- Could NOT find ElfUtils (missing:  LIBDW_LIBRARY LIBDW_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.

Comment: "kcov/" : See the text file INSTALL.md : `RH/Centos/Fedora you'll need
elfutils-devel and *not* elfutils-libelf-devel.` .... Please read my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you Knud. It's working fine now. Thank you for your help